# I used a generalized linear model with multiple dependent variables in R

Tags: poisson

I used a generalized linear model with multiple variables in R .my data (young) looks like below and I have 5 DVS(dv1,dv2,dv3,dv4,dv5) and three IVS(IV1,IV2,IV3) as a data frame. I keep getting the error below , can some one answer please , as to I am doing wrong.

```
> head(young)
  IV1 IV2 IV3 DVS
1  18   1   1 dv1
2  20   1   1 dv1
3  21   2   1 dv1
4  21   1   2 dv1
5  22   1   1 dv1
6  22   1   1 dv1
> models <- list()
> dvnames <- paste("DVS", 1:5, sep='')
> ivnames <- paste("IV", 1:3, sep='') ## for some value of 3
> for (y in dvnames){
+ form <- formula(paste(y, "~", ivnames))
+ models[[y]] <- glm(form, data=young, family='poisson') }
**Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'DVS1' not found**
```

Comment: Please try to explain the terminology you use; I had to think for a few minutes what DVS was and why you had 5 of them (admittedly I am sans coffee, and your data has one dependent variable from what you show). A reproducible example would be nice.

Comment: This seems to be about misunderstanding what R syntax to use. You seem to know what you want to do.

Comment: @NickCox Agreed and I've already voted to close, but unless the Ebby updates the question to be clear to us about what they want to do (it makes little sense at the moment) this will get short shrift on [so] (where it is being earmarked for migration to).

Comment: Just a note: it's almost always better to use `reformulate` instead of `formula` and `paste`.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see why you get the error. The first time the loop iterates, `y` takes the value `DVS1`. In a model formula, R will look for a variable in `young` with the name `DVS1`. As you have shown us, there is no variable (column) with that name (nor presumably an object with that within the scope of `glm()`) and hence

```
**Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'DVS1' not found**
```

Which is quite correct.

Now the more important question becomes, what are you trying to do? You seem to be fitting a Poisson model but you claim the response variables are in a single column, `DVS`, which R will be treating as a factor variable. Where are the count data that you wish to model as some function of `IV1`, `IV2`, and `IV3`?

R expects to be supplied something it can interpret as a numeric count for the left-hand-side of the formula (where you are putting `y`).